# Query array of object in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design, nosql

i have a collection that is called `employees`, which includes documents and each document contains some data, and an array of objects that is called `orgsanizations`, for instance:

```
orgsanizations: [
{
orgId: 'org1',
registrationDate: '08/05/2021',
status: 'pending'
},
{
orgId: 'org2,
registrationDate: '12/01/2021',
status: 'approved'
}
];
```

I am trying to retrieve all the documents in `employees` that contains orgId === org1 in the `orgsanizations`, here is what i tried to do but keeps returning empty array.

```
  const allEmployees = async () => {
    const employeesList = db.collection('employees');
    const snapshot = await employeesList
      .where('orgsanizations', 'array-contains', { orgId: 'org1' })
      .get();
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log(snapshot.empty);
    } else {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data());
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Is there a solution for this or should start considering changing the structure to something else?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can't check for the contents of a map, using `array-contains`.  There are a couple of solutions for this...

1. Create a second array called `orgIds`, which contains only the `orgId` strings.  You can then find any documents which contain these orgIds.  To achieve this, you will need to write the `orgId` into the map AND the `orgIds` array.
2. Create an `organizations` sub-collection of your `employee` document and use a `collectionGroup` query.

```
{
  organizations: [
    {orgId: 'org1', registrationDate: '08/05/2021', status: 'pending'},
    {orgId: 'org2', registrationDate: '12/01/2021', status: 'approved'}
  ],
  orgIds: ['org1', 'org2']
}
```

```
const employeesList = db.collection('employees');
const snapshot = await employeesList
.where('orgIds', 'array-contains', 'org1')
.get();
```

You may also want to change your `registrationDate` to either a Timestamp or an ISO8601 string, so that you can sort them (if needed).